# Reshaping Binary images into 1D vector Python

Tags: python-2.7, matlab, image-processing, vector, opencv, python

I am working on an Image Processing Project and I am a beginner in Python. Any help would be appreciated.I am trying to convert matlab code to python.Below is my matlab code-

```
file_name='play.png';
message=double(imread(file_name));
Mm=size(message,1);                         %Height
Nm=size(message,2);                         %Width
message_vector=round(reshape(message,1200,1)./256);
disp(message_vector)
```

[Output of matlab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4fVU.png)

Below is python code

```
water = cv2.imread('sam.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(water, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
file_name=im2double(gray_image)
a=np.shape(gray_image)
b=a[0]*a[1]#getting resolution
images_rs = gray_image.reshape([b, 1])#reshaping array into 1D vector
print(images_rs)
```

[Output of python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot0aZ.png)

I want output like what i get for matlab code with 1 and 0. How can i get that?Where I made mistake in python as the answer in python is not same as Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not normalize the values in python after reshaping. Updating `images_rs = gray_image.reshape([b, 1])` to `images_rs = gray_image.reshape([b, 1])/256.` should give what you're looking for.